# How can I get all 6000 photos back out of Samsung Cloud at once rather than doing them separately?

Tags: samsung, cloud

My Samsung Cloud storage is full, and it turns out I have about 13GB of photos (over 6000 photos) in there, that have been synced from my phone.

However, I only have around maybe 1GB of photos on my phone. Clearly the majority of photos in my Samsung Cloud are not on my phone anymore.

The first part of my question is, is there any chance that there may be *some* photos on my cloud account which Samsung has deleted from my phone automatically to clear space, assuming I'm happy that it's still in the cloud?

And the second part is, how can I sync them *back* to my phone, or even a PC, so I have them again? I can't find an option on the phone and I went to the Samsung Cloud site and browsed my photos, but there's no way to methodically download photos in bulk, and scrolling beyond the first few hundred becomes painful. Is there seriously no way on either my phone or a PC to download *all* my photos again rather than selecting a few at a time?

Note: "Select all" on the web interface only selects those visible on screen and the system prevents you selecting more than 500.

Comment: You can't just select the whole directory to download via a long press or options menu?

Comment: Not on the web interface.  I've since discovered there's a Microsoft Store app that is supposed to be able to sync your cloud photos to your PC.  So I am trying this.